# Primes $n=\overline{10101\cdots01}$ with $k$ ones.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Find all primes $n=\overline{10101\cdots01}$ with $k$ ones.

The number is in standard base 10.

Comment: What do you mean with the overline? Do you simply mean the numbers that are "10", concatenated k times?

Comment: @CBenni I thought that was standard notation. Not quite, $10$'s are concatenated $k-1$ times, plus one more $1$ in the end (since there are $k$ ones).

Comment: The overline is standard notation for *infinite* repetitions in digits after a decimal point. For instance, $0.\overline{1}$ would be $\frac{1}{9}=0.11111...$. It is also possible you wanted an *underbrace* labelled $k-1$, as in $$\underbrace{1010\cdots10}_{k-1}1.$$ Anyway, what are your thoughts? Are you able to write an explicit formula for such numbers? (Hint: geometric sum formula.)

Comment: Perhaps Wikipedia's remarks abut [repunit primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit#Repunit_primes) will help (your numbers are repunits in base 100). It gives arguments that there are only finitely many repunit primes in base 4, 8, and 9 -- they may be generalizable to other perfect square bases.

Comment: I'm sorry, in Serbian workbooks it's a standard notation and it's almost never explained what it means, since it's clear from context when it represents repeating digits and when it represents digits stacked together instead of multiplication, for example $\overline{ab}=10a+b$. I just used it here (just as the workbook used it),  to clear up confusion that $\cdots$ could be multiplication signs (for example $\overline{a_1b_1\cdots z_1}\neq a_1b_1\cdots z_1$}) (although it's quite obvious they're not).

Answer (score 3):

We have $99n=99\cdot \underbrace{10\ldots 10}_k1=\underbrace{9\ldots9}_{2(k+1)}=100^{k+1}-1=(10^{k+1}-1)(10^{k+1}+1)$.
If $n$ is prime (and of course $>99$), the smaller factor must be a divisor of $99$, especially $10^{k+1}-1\le 99$, hence $k\le 1$. Thus $n=101$ is the only solution.